# Trying to find the worst case scenario in a time-series

Tags: python, time-series, scenarios

I am trying to build a program in Python, which would find the worst case scenario which in my case is when one variable is at its highest and the others at its minimum. I have 3 time-series the first one has demand, and the other two have production of Solar PV and Wind Turbines. I want to find the hour of the year during which I have the worst case (as I mentioned, during which the Demand it at its highest and Production at lowest).

My dataset looks like this, I am showing you two days, but my data are a year.

```
date;demand;pv;wind
2021/01/01 02:00:00;4316;0;1168
2021/01/01 03:00:00;4136;0;1087
2021/01/01 04:00:00;3830;0;1029
2021/01/01 05:00:00;3652;0;896
2021/01/01 06:00:00;3664;0;812
2021/01/01 07:00:00;3772;0;740
2021/01/01 08:00:00;3913;2;586
2021/01/01 09:00:00;4144;231;536
2021/01/01 10:00:00;4696;876;460
2021/01/01 11:00:00;5221;1426;394
2021/01/01 12:00:00;5556;1704;360
2021/01/01 13:00:00;5574;1772;328
2021/01/01 14:00:00;5241;1666;296
2021/01/01 15:00:00;4666;1401;256
2021/01/01 16:00:00;4507;903;189
2021/01/01 17:00:00;4502;259;167
2021/01/01 18:00:00;4833;4;118
2021/01/01 19:00:00;5367;0;105
2021/01/01 20:00:00;5508;0;105
2021/01/01 21:00:00;5544;0;91
2021/01/01 22:00:00;5442;0;100
2021/01/01 23:00:00;5192;0;100
2021/01/02 00:00:00;4878;0;105
2021/01/02 01:00:00;4468;0;112
2021/01/02 02:00:00;4096;0;123
2021/01/02 03:00:00;3999;0;121
2021/01/02 04:00:00;3855;0;124
2021/01/02 05:00:00;3751;0;158
2021/01/02 06:00:00;3771;0;191
2021/01/02 07:00:00;3946;0;241
2021/01/02 08:00:00;4146;1;309
2021/01/02 09:00:00;4365;190;360
2021/01/02 10:00:00;4793;673;357
2021/01/02 11:00:00;5084;1025;332
2021/01/02 12:00:00;5308;1205;311
2021/01/02 13:00:00;5499;1174;333
2021/01/02 14:00:00;5577;1028;369
2021/01/02 15:00:00;5507;737;420
2021/01/02 16:00:00;5482;367;470
2021/01/02 17:00:00;5456;74;539
2021/01/02 18:00:00;5660;0;653
2021/01/02 19:00:00;6017;0;804
2021/01/02 20:00:00;5996;0;994
2021/01/02 21:00:00;5905;0;1255
2021/01/02 22:00:00;5667;0;1563
2021/01/02 23:00:00;5301;0;1782
2021/01/03 00:00:00;4957;0;1785
2021/01/03 01:00:00;4500;0;1845
2021/01/03 02:00:00;4105;0;1949
2021/01/03 03:00:00;3975;0;2025
2021/01/03 04:00:00;3780;0;2137
2021/01/03 05:00:00;3685;0;2223
2021/01/03 06:00:00;3707;0;2132
2021/01/03 07:00:00;3825;0;2131
2021/01/03 08:00:00;3985;0;1951
2021/01/03 09:00:00;4238;77;1890
2021/01/03 10:00:00;4756;388;1750
2021/01/03 11:00:00;5194;716;1614
2021/01/03 12:00:00;5498;981;1635
2021/01/03 13:00:00;5640;1150;1608
2021/01/03 14:00:00;5635;1047;1537
2021/01/03 15:00:00;5296;854;1417
2021/01/03 16:00:00;5234;489;1317
2021/01/03 17:00:00;5135;123;1207
2021/01/03 18:00:00;5416;1;1208
2021/01/03 19:00:00;5913;0;1242
2021/01/03 20:00:00;5972;0;1332
2021/01/03 21:00:00;5897;0;1347
2021/01/03 22:00:00;5710;0;1353
2021/01/03 23:00:00;5234;0;1473
2021/01/04 00:00:00;4842;0;1530
2021/01/04 01:00:00;4390;0;1612
```

Thanks any advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compute the i that minimizes the expression

```
pv[i] + wind[i] - demand[i]
```

representing the surplus (or shortage) of energy with respect to the demand

Comment: you can also create an histogram with size of (say) seven days of the week and all values to be average of those seven days you are arbitrating. This way you can avoid a sudden one day event that had the perfect minimum demand or maximum production.